# ANT unzip every jar except one

Tags: java, jar, ant

I have an ANT target that unzips every jar with a "for" task, but I want to exclude a specific jar called Neo.jar. This is what I have so far, but it is unzipping every single jar that is available to it.

```
 <target name="unzipjars">
   <for param="jar">
     <sequential>
       <unzip dest="${expanded.dirs}" src="@{jar}">
         <exclude name="Neo.jar/**"/>
       </unzip>
     </sequential>
   </for>
 </target>
```

I was looking at trying to exclude something from "for param="jar"" but I don't think anything like that exists. The "exclude name" for Neo.jar doesn't seem to work because I believe it doesn't think it is a directory because it is a jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the if task (http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) to filter out the Neo.jar file. For example

```
<for param="jar">
  <sequential>
    <if>
      <not><equals arg1="@{jar}" arg2="Neo.jar" /></not>
      <then><!-- unzip the jar --></then>
    </if>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: error, "equals doesn't support the nested "then" element."

Comment: Messed up my question, edited my question to use "@" instead of "$" for jar, maybe that changes something?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html), it's quietly easy.

All you need is to add the tag `patternset` to your configuration (and you don't need to iterate by the way...). Like this:

```
<target name="unzipjars">
    <unzip dest="${expanded.dirs}">
        <patternset>
            <exclude name="**/Neo.jar"/>
        </patternset>
        <fileset dir="${jar}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </unzip>
</target>
```

Comment: Voted up for avoiding ant-contrib and doing it all in one `unzip` task.